# How to pass a string argument from HTML (using JavaScript) to a Java executable Jar?

Tags: javascript, java, command-line-arguments

My project takes a query string as an argument and searches a directory using LSI. I want to set up a local server and pass the query string from an HTML file to the Jar.

I will use JavaScript to create buttons and handle events, so for example, on pressing the search button a string in the text box should be passed to the .Jar file like a command like argument. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have any problem to do that. For sending the query to the java application on the local server you could use either a form or AJAX and then once received the string on the java server you could execute whatever code you need to run on the local machine.

If you have any other problem on setting that up please don't hesitate to ask ok?